# BODY_SENSORS permission removed when publishing to Play

Tags: wear-os

I made an app that works fine in debug, but when I publish to Play it appears to remove the BODY_SENSORS permission from the mobile app and so when it tries to install the Wear app it gives an error "Host application permissions are not set".﻿

Is it possible to publish a Wear app to Play that measures heart rate?

Comment: Add the BODY_SENSORS permission to wear and to mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer - it's because BODY_SENSORS was added in SDK 20 and all released devices are 19 or less. 20 is L Preview.

I'm hoping that it works on L Preview.﻿

Comment: All wear devices have the sdk=20. Android-L is 21.